# Migration from Hibernate to EclipseLink in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an application created in Spring Boot https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. I need to replace Hibernate provider with EclipseLink.The problem is that practically the entire configuration is found only in the `application. properties` https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/resources/application.yml file and I don't know what to change to EclipseLink.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example project from Spring on how to use Spring Boot with EclipseLink. Please refer:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/eclipselink